# If I'm using AmazonHttpClient to send Rest request to AWS services, how do I add Multipart ability?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, httpclient, multipart

If I'm using AmazonHttpClient to send Rest request to AWS services, how do I add Multipart ability?
I want to send Multipart requests.
I have a working code that uses apache httpclient API: CloseableHttpClient + HttpRequestBase + MultipartEntityBuilder in order to send such requests.

But couldn't find how to use it with AWS AmazonHttpClient :(

Thanks!

I didn't find how to make AmazonHttpClient to work with the apache API (or maybe AWS has it's API? I didn't find, also asked ChatGPT but he sent me a code that combines those two (AmazonHttpClient + apache httpclient) but looks like it's not actually works togrther.

Comment: What AWS API do you want to interact via multipart with? Do you have your own application behind e.g. an API Gateway and want to interact with that?

Comment: There are over 200 AWS Services. What Service do you want to interact with.

Comment: Hi @luk2302
Actually I'm not sure, The Multipart feature that we have works with basic authentication on every Multipart server.
I thought that it's the same idea here, I understand that it depends on which service I'm sending to? I believe that S3 is a common use case, but I'm not sure . . .

Comment: Yes: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html - but *that* multipart has little to do with `MultipartEntityBuilder`. Basically for S3 this is used for uploading multiple parts of the same object separately. Afaik the `MultipartEntityBuilder` is used to e.g. send multiple data sets in one request, basically the opposite. Maybe the naming was really bad... What are you *actually* trying to achieve here?

Comment: We have an application that sends Rest requests,
It supports several authentication methods (AWS, GCP, OCI, basic authentication and some more . . .)
Recently we added the ability to send Multipart requests (instead of one block Body, there is a table mush like Postman, it works well with basic authentication and with no authentication.
This was written with the apache httpclient lib.
So AWS requests are been sent with their own invoker based on AmazonHttpClient  so I'll have to add the Multipart also in that invoker but I'm not sure how exactly.
Thanks!